# Meaning of "threaten"

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

According to Merriam-Webster, *threaten* has the following four meanings:

> 1: to utter threats against
>
> 2a: to give signs or warning of
>
> 2b: to hang over dangerously
>
> 3: to announce as intended or possible
>
> 4: to cause to feel insecure or anxious

There is one sentence:

> The lecturer's monotonous delivery **threatened** to put us to sleep.

What does *threaten* mean in the above sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A different dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/threaten) gives better definitions here. It's always worth consulting more than one dictionary if the first is inconclusive.

> **threaten**
>   *verb
>
>   [with object]*
>   **2** cause (someone or something) to be vulnerable or at risk; endanger:
>       *a broken finger threatened his career
>
>       one of four London hospitals threatened with closure*
>           • *[with infinitive]* seem likely to produce an unpleasant or unwelcome result:
>             *the dispute threatened to spread to other cities*

In threatening to put an audience to sleep, it's the "seem likely to produce an unpleasant or unwelcome result" meaning:

> The lecturer's monotonous delivery seemed likely to produce the unwelcome result of  putting us to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

From your list

> to give signs or warning of

Fits. It was so boring, that it gave signs that it could put the listeners asleep.